# JQuery scrollTop function for adjusting css not working

Tags: jquery, css, shopify

I'm trying to shrink the `margin-top` value on scroll since I'm using an announcement bar that disappears on scroll.

Here is the script with the CSS I'm currently using, it's all in the theme.liquid file (I'm using Shopify):

```
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
           $('#christmas-header-image-pc').addClass('christmas-header-image-margin');
        } else {
           $('#christmas-header-image-pc').removeClass('christmas-header-image-margin');
        }
    });
</script>

      <style>
      #christmas-header-image-pc {
          top:0!important;
          margin-top:120px;
          z-index:5;
          height:auto;
          position:fixed;
        }
      .christmas-header-image-margin {
          margin-top:55px;
      }
      </style>

      <img id="christmas-header-image-pc" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0568/1191/3367/files/christmas-header-decoration.svg?v=1638965731">
```

I can't seem to get it working.
The value needs to go from `120px` to `55px`.

On the frontend this is happening right now:
[image]

This is happening when I scroll:
[image]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like your `jQuery` is working just fine, the new class is being added to the image after the `scrollTop` is above 50.

Your issue has to do with CSS Specificity, add the ID to the new class ruleset like this:

```
#christmas-header-image-pc.christmas-header-image-margin {
  margin-top:55px;
}
```

Here's a great [article by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) about the topic of specificity.

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied. Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed of different sorts of CSS selectors.

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
  if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
     jQuery('#christmas-header-image-pc').addClass('christmas-header-image-margin');
  } else {
     jQuery('#christmas-header-image-pc').removeClass('christmas-header-image-margin');
  }
});
```

```css
section {
  min-height:2000px;
}

#christmas-header-image-pc {
    top:0!important;
    margin-top:120px;
    z-index:5;
    height:auto;
    position:fixed;
    transition:300ms;
  }
#christmas-header-image-pc.christmas-header-image-margin {
    margin-top:55px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <img id="christmas-header-image-pc" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0568/1191/3367/files/christmas-header-decoration.svg?v=1638965731">
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the problem. Works like charm.